# Send data from one activity to another class(Not Activity)

Tags: java, android, android-layout, sharedpreferences

I want to send data from one activity to another class but the second class is not an activity. It extends Framelayout.

```
if (imageHolder1 != null) {
        FrameLayout.LayoutParams lp = new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(
                LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
                Gravity.CENTER);
        ImageCell newView = new ImageCell(this);
        resourceId = R.drawable.tile;
        newView.setBackgroundResource(resourceId);
        // newView.setImageResource(resourceId);
        imageHolder1.addView(newView, lp);
        TextView tv =newView.getTextView();
        tv.setText("A");
        SharedPreferences pref = getSharedPreferences("A", MODE_WORLD_WRITEABLE);
        Editor edt = pref.edit();
        edt.putString("A", tv.toString());
        edt.commit();
        newView.getPointTxtView().setText("5");

        newView.mEmpty = false;
        newView.mCellNumber = -1;
        mLastNewCell = newView;
        mImageCount++;

        newView.setOnClickListener(this);
        newView.setOnLongClickListener(this);
        newView.setOnTouchListener(this);

    }

if (imageHolder2 != null) {
            FrameLayout.LayoutParams lp = new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(
                    LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
                    Gravity.CENTER);
            ImageCell newView = new ImageCell(this);
            resourceId = R.drawable.tile;
            // newView.setImageResource(resourceId);
            newView.setBackgroundResource(resourceId);
            imageHolder2.addView(newView, lp);
//          newView.getTextView().setText("B");
            TextView tv =newView.getTextView();
            tv.setText("B");
            SharedPreferences pref = getSharedPreferences("A", MODE_PRIVATE);
            Editor edt = pref.edit();
            edt.putString("A", (String) tv.getText());
            edt.commit();
            newView.getPointTxtView().setText("2");

            newView.mEmpty = false;
            newView.mCellNumber = -1;
            mLastNewCell = newView;
            mImageCount++;

            newView.setOnClickListener(this);
            newView.setOnLongClickListener(this);
            newView.setOnTouchListener(this);

        }
```

Here my another class

```
pref = getContext().getSharedPreferences("A", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);


    textView.setText(pref.getString("A", null));
    Log.e("ad", "awd" + pref.getString("A", null));
    Log.i("Position:", "" + mCellNumber);

    int column = mCellNumber % total_col;
    int row = mCellNumber / total_col;
    Log.i("Column:", "" + column);
    Log.i("Row:", "" + row);
```

But i am get android.widget.textview as my text....
Now the problem is in another class sharedpreference is not working because it is not an activity. Hope to receive help from someone.

Comment: Whats wrong with SP?

Comment: I am not able to call SharedPreferences pref = getSharedPreferences("A", MODE_WORLD_WRITEABLE);

Comment: For that you non -activity class you need to use context for getSharedPreferences() method. Like context.getSharedPreferences.

Comment: your issue solved now??

Comment: No, I have updated my code but my text is setting as "android.widget.Textviews" instead of text

Comment: you need to change this  `edt.putString("A", tv.getText().toString());`

Comment: So what i will have to change.....

Comment: I have told you. See my above comment.

Comment: Get text from TextView "textView.getText().toString();

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try,

```
SharedPreferences pref = getContext().getSharedPreferences("A", Context.MODE_WORLD_WRITEABLE);
```

Instead of using

```
Editor edt = pref.edit();
edt.putString("A", tv.toString());
edt.commit();
```

use

```
Editor edt = pref.edit();
edt.putString("A", tv.getText().toString());
edt.commit();
```

Comment: Simply use Context.MODE_WORLD_WRITEABLE @Mehdi

Comment: No, I have updated my code but my text is setting as "android.widget.Textviews" instead of text

Comment: Bro there is one problem  i have set two different values for different textviews now in another class i want to show the selected textview value using sharedpreference.  I have updated my code look at it..

Answer (score 1):

SharedPreferences object in any Layout class

```
this.getContext().getSharedPreferences("A", MODE_WORLD_WRITEABLE);
```

Please make sure Context should be same,which one you used for saving any object in SharedPreferences...Hope this will help.

Comment: Use 

edt.putString("A", tv.getText().toString());   

to save char sequence of TextView

Answer (score 1):

you can pass values by constrictor like this

```
public class YourClass extends FrameLayout {

private String value;

public YourClass(Context context, String value) {
    super(context);
    this.value = value;
}

public YourClass(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, String value) {
    super(context, attrs);
    this.value = value;
}

public YourClass(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle, String value) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    this.value = value;
}
```

}

or you can create class extend Application and define SharedPreferences on it like this

```
public class YourClass extends Application {

private static SharedPreferences sharedPreferences;

public static SharedPreferences getSharedPreferences() {
    return sharedPreferences;
}

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    YourClass.sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this.getApplicationContext());
}
```

}

then, you can call SharedPreferences like this

```
SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = YourClass.getSharedPreferences();
sharedPreferences.getString("","");
YourClass.getSharedPreferences().getString("","");
```

and be sure to set application name in AndroidManifest.xml like this

```
<application
        android:name=".YourClass" .... />
```

you can call SharedPreferences anywhere on project

Answer (score 1):

You can use `SharedPreference` in non-Activity class.
`SharedPreference` is related to `Context`. So, The solution is:

1. Define a static `Context` class in an `Activity` class.

   public static Context mAppContext;
2. Initialize the `mAppContext` in using the `getApplicationContext` method.

   public void onCreate() {
       mAppContext= getApplicationContext();
   }
3. Get the `SharedPreferences` with the `YourActivity.mAppContext`.

   SharedPreferences prefs = YourActivity.mAppContext.getSharedPreferences("A", MODE_WORLD_WRITEABLE);

Comment: No, I have updated my code but my text is setting as "android.widget.Textviews" instead of text

Answer (score 0):

Create a static object in other class while creating instance of that class setvalue of that object

For eg:

```
  XYZ xyz=new XYZ(context);
  xyz.somestaticvariable=somevalue;
```

Also you are doing a simple mistake you are using 
`tv.toString();`
 instead use 
`tv.getText();`

Comment: is it not possible using sharedpreference? Can you please just tell me from my above code how to send data

Comment: yes it posible with sharedpreference but i would suggest this over sharedpreference.

Comment: so basically can you please just elaborate how to send data in my above code

Comment: to get data from shared preference use preference.getString("key",defaultvalue); show me how you are doing this

Comment: No, I have updated my code but my text is setting as "android.widget.Textviews" instead of text

Comment: Can you please just solve another issue. I have set different text for different textviews. Now i have to send all values to another class that extends Framelayout. But in another class i have to getstring as per my need now suppose if i select first textview then it should value of first textview using shared preference......See my updated Code

Comment: either use my suggested way or use multiple preference and check null pointer while getting value

Comment: Can you please provide me pseudo code to use multiple preference and check null pointer...

Comment: sorry do R&D yourself

Answer (score 0):

You don't care about your class is activity or not. Because getSharedPreference() is a method of Context class.

Change

```
SharedPreferences pref = getSharedPreferences("A", MODE_WORLD_WRITEABLE);
```

to

```
SharedPreferences pref = getContext().getSharedPreferences("A", MODE_WORLD_WRITEABLE);
```

Comment: No, I have updated my code but my text is setting as "android.widget.Textviews" instead of text

Comment: change edt.putString("A", tv.toString()); to edt.putString("A", tv.getText().toString()); see answer of Chirag Jain